# Batch Google search or search inside Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-search

I have a list of cities that I want coordinates for. I've been typing in the city in Google Search (in the format: *city name coordinates*—for example `Recife coordinates`) and then pasting the result back on my local spreadsheet.

Then I thought: well, I am using two Google products, they must communicate somehow… So, how can I make this process less copy-and-pasty?

Answer (score 2):

One big copy-and-paste from the [Wikipedia list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_by_latitude), and then delete the ones you don't want.

Answer (score 2):

## Short answer

Don't do batch Google searches.

## Explanation

Doing automated queries could block you, your equipment, network, your app/script, etc. from getting results from Google Search, so instead of usign Google Search use the [Google Apps Script Maps service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/maps/). See [Tutorial: Getting to Know the Maps Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/maps_tutorial) to learn more.

## References

["Unusual traffic from your computer network" - Search Help](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/86640?hl=en)